# How to read an asset file on click - android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-listview, sdk

I have following fields on my screen:

editText, textView and a button

I would like it to do the following:

When user enters the name of the file in editText field (.txt files only) and presses submit button, textView will display the contents of that txt files.

I have searched multiple tutorials but I cant really find a solution..

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Edit: Please not that txt files are already populated and stored in assets folder

Comment: A random file with a .txt extension is not the same as an asset.

Comment: @Merlevede well its not a random file. Only file specified by the user will be displayed?

Comment: @sarkar where in java file does this go? and do i need to declare anything?

Comment: you do not need to do anything else. just write my code and you have be sure that the name provided in edittext matches exectly as the name of file present in assets (including extension )

Answer (score 1):

```
 BufferedReader pemReader = null;
    pemReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(context.getAssets().open(edittext.getText().toString())));
    StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
    String line = null;
 while ((line = pemReader.readLine()) != null) {
 content.append(line);
}

textview.setText(content.toString());
```